# What is the event for something getting named?

Tags: minecraft, bukkit

I've looked though the [entity event reference](http://jd.bukkit.org/beta/apidocs/org/bukkit/event/entity/package-summary.html), but I can't seem to locate the event for when something gets named.

Am I missing it, or does it not exist and I will have to call getCustomName() on things regularly? That could get spammy fast.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does not seem to be an EventHandler for something getting named explicitly as of right now. There might be some workaround using a different event to piggyback on to turn down the frequency of running getCustomName()

For example, if you're dealing with someone using name tags on entities you could use

```
PlayerInteractEntityEvent
```

Here's a List of all the available events and descriptions for them
http://jd.bukkit.org/rb/apidocs/org/bukkit/event/class-use/Event.html

Comment: Hm. I like that idea, my only concern that that as the time the event fires the entity will not be named yet.

Comment: it would be named very shortly after so you could have some kind of delay OR maybe set a variable like Boolean checkNames = true; then on that recursive check that you were thinking about just have it set to only run if checkNames is true and then after run set checkNames to false again?

Comment: Perhaps. I'll have to play...it's annoying there's not an onEntityChange event either, thought that would probably fire 9 million times a tick. I'll approve if I don't get any other answers in a day. Thanks for the advice. :)

Comment: there is the PlayerItemHeldEvent which fires when people change their held item.. most likely to happen with a now empty hand after using a name tag on an entity? although might want to set a cooldown on it xD i personally tend to scroll through my held items just to watch it go around but that would happen frequently and no where near as frequent as a "onEntityChange" .. that would be insane.

Comment: What about a bukkit runnable that gets called every 10 ticks, loops threw all living entities, and checks if they have the same name as before using a `HashMap`?

Comment: @jojodmo I think that's what he meant about what he wasn't sure he wanted to do and just wanted a command that would give him an update without much overhead